# Update EditorTemplate with data returned from ajax call

Tags: html, ajax, asp.net-mvc-5

I have an EditorTemplate which is rendered from a main view using the following:

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => Model.Alarms)
```

The data within Model.Alarms will be refreshed and returned at a regular rate via the following call:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
    $('#updateAlarms').click(function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: '@Url.Action("updateAlarms", "Dashboard")',
            dataType: "json",
            success: successFunc
        });

        function successFunc(data, status) {
            alert('success');
        }

        function errorFunc() {
            alert('error');
        }
    });
});
```

The EditorTemplate looks like this:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Dashboard";
}

<div class="panel panel-primary">
    <div class="@GetBackgroundColour(Model.IsConditionNormal)" id="alarmTitleBackground">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <h3 class="panel-title alarmDescription" style="text-align:center">@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.ConditionDescription)</h3>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="@GetBackgroundColour(Model.IsConditionNormal)" id="alarmTextBackground">
        <table style="text-align:left">
            <tr>
                <td><p class="alarmLabel1" style="color:white">@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.AlarmLabel1)</p></td>
                <td><p class="alarmValue1" style="color:white">@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.AlarmValue1)</p></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><p class="alarmLabel2" style="color:white">@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.AlarmLabel2)</p></td>
                <td><p class="alarmValue2" style="color:white">@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.AlarmValue2)</p></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><p class="alarmLabel3" style="color:white">@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.AlarmLabel3)</p></td>
                <td><p class="alarmValue3" style="color:white">@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.AlarmValue3)</p></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

At the moment I can't figure out how to link the returned data from the ajax call to the data passed into the EditorFor, how can I do this?

UPDATE:

Here is my cut down view model:

```
    public class DashboardViewModel
{
    public List<SSAlarm> Alarms { get; set; }
}

public class SSAlarm
{
    public Boolean IsConditionNormal { get; set; }
    public String ConditionDescription { get; set; }
    public String AlarmLabel1 { get; set; }
    public String AlarmValue1 { get; set; }
    public String AlarmLabel2 { get; set; }
    public String AlarmValue2 { get; set; }
    public String AlarmLabel3 { get; set; }
    public String AlarmValue3 { get; set; }
}
```

And a temp version of the controller action to show what is being returned (I've hardcoded the return data in here at the moment):

```
public JsonResult UpdateAlarms(String id)
    {
        DashboardViewModel model = new DashboardViewModel();

        model.Alarms = new List<SSAlarm>()
        {
            new SSAlarm
            {
                ConditionDescription = "Condition Normal",
                IsConditionNormal  = true
            },

            new SSAlarm
            {
                ConditionDescription = "Lost neutral alarm",
                IsConditionNormal = false,
                AlarmLabel1 = "Phase Voltage Red:",
                AlarmValue1 = "230V",
                AlarmLabel2 = "Phase Voltage Yellow:",
                AlarmValue2 = "231V",
                AlarmLabel3 = "Phase Voltage Blue:",
                AlarmValue3 = "232V"
             }
        };

        return Json(model);
    }
```

Comment: What is the data you are returning and how does it relate to the elements in your template? - you can use something like `$('alarmLabel1').text(data.someValue);`

Comment: The data is a list of the following class:

`public class SSAlarm
    {
        public Boolean IsConditionNormal { get; set; }
        public String ConditionDescription { get; set; }
        public String AlarmLabel1 { get; set; }
        public String AlarmValue1 { get; set; }
        public String AlarmLabel2 { get; set; }
        public String AlarmValue2 { get; set; }
        public String AlarmLabel3 { get; set; }
        public String AlarmValue3 { get; set; }
    }`

Comment: You need to edit you question with the code, not in comments. And what do you mean a _list_ (how can you set a collection of items when you view has only one item? Show the controller method which is returning the json.

Comment: And if `Model.Alarms` is `IEnumerable<T>` then you need to change your template so your not creating duplicate `id` attributes (`alarmTitleBackground` and `alarmTextBackground`)

Comment: I've added the updated code to the question @StephenMuecke, apologies for not doing so first time round.

Comment: Based on your edit, will your `UpdateAlarms()` method return exactly the same number of items that you initially generated?

Comment: No, thats a bit misleading, again apologies for that. The number of Alarms could be differ each time the data is returned.

Comment: So if you has say 10 initial `Alarm` and your method returns only 4, how do you identify which ones are to be updated? - you don't seem to have any `ID` property.

Comment: What I'm trying to get to is almost a complete refresh. So on initial load I will be presented with 10 Alarms which are essentially panels containing some text. The next refresh wouldn't update those 10 but replace them with the 4 new alarms, so I would now only see 4 panels on screen.

Comment: It that case you would be far better of returning a partial view rather than json - say `return PartialView("_Alarms", model);` where `_Alarms.cshtml` is `@model `List<SSAlarm>` and has `@Html.EditorFor(m => m)` But since you not ediitng anything, it really should be a `DisplayTemplate`, not an `EditorTemplate`

Comment: Ok, thats works perfect with the PartialView and changing to DisplayTemplate. Thanks for the help @StephenMuecke

Comment: You may as well also remove all your class names (`class="alarmLabel1"` etc) unless you really using those to style you elements with css.